# Forcing Dispose() while debugging

Tags: .net, idisposable, finalizer

I know it isn't standard practice, but are there any downsides or better alternatives to doing the following?  I just want to make sure the code is being used properly, and .NET doesn't do anything for you to ensure it.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Some managed shutdown logic...
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

#if DEBUG
        // Why is ConditionalAttribute not allowed if you can still achieve this with compiler directives?
        // [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        ~SFtpClient()
        {
            Debug.Fail("This class is IDisposable and should be wrapped by using {}");
        }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good to me because that conditional will prevent the un-necessary Finalizing cost of an empty Finalizer in RELEASE builds.  Might want to add the #if DEBUG around the GC.SupressFinalize, too.

The [Conditional("DEBUG")] tells the *compiler* not to call the method, but the method is still there.  You can't compile a call the Finalize() method, anyway.  The GC Finalizer doesn't check the attribute.

Comment: Good point, I don't have a finalizer in Release, and the empty `Finalize()` in `Object` doesn't get compiled (special treatment?).  Thus, `GC.SupressFinalize` is unnecessary.

Comment: You mean `ConditionalAttribute` tells the **runtime** not to call the method?  I suppose that makes sense, since it is a decorator after all and giving this one special treatment would further confuse things.

Comment: No it doesn't tell the *runtime* not to call the method. It tells the compiler of the calling code to leave out that method call. And the C# compiler never creates the code calling the `Finalize` method.

Comment: No, I mean the CS/VB.NET/whatever compiler knows to check the attribute.  If you have [Conditional("DEBUG")] above a method, but the compiler of the calling assembly (whether the same assembly or a different assembly) will only emit the method invocation of the calling assembly if a compiler directive for DEBUG is set.  Conditional has no runtime effect (just compile-time).

Comment: By the way, I've read that it is up to the compiler to do it, so if you're using a novel compiler, you might want to check the behavior of your compiler to be sure.

Comment: Oh, got it!  So with further research I found that's how the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` methods work. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use FxCop and watch for [CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: That's true, unfortunately we don't use FxCop.  Yes, I know we should. :)

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunate. You should.